# Why the text not appear in the android page when I use targetsdkversion 30 but it work when I use targetsdkversion 28?

Tags: android

What is the problem in :

When I use targetsdkversion 30 the text not appears** As it is shown in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBIUV.png)

And When I use targetsdkversion 28 the text appears** As it is shown in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExdY6.png)

Comment: your pictures aren't attached

Comment: Maybe is better is you can reproduce your error with a small code